# C: getline does not read the full document

Tags: c, windows, segmentation-fault, mingw, getline

I need to write a program in C reading in a big XML file with getline, the problem is only 2085 of the approxemately 3 billion lines are read. In the following code the problem occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()                                          
{
    size_t l = 0;
    char *line;

    line = NULL;
    while (getline(&line,&l,stdin)>0) {

        getline(&line,&l,stdin);
        printf("%s\n", line);
        printf("%i\n", i);

        free(line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My first goal would be to display the lines, with printf so I can work with that.
Neither line from 2080 til 2090 is empty.
If I change the loop-condition to >=0 about 80.000 are read in and if I comment the printf out, about 130.00 lines. But instead I get an segmentation error. Which I really don't know how to solve in this case.
I am using Visual Studio Code to edit and MYSYS2 MinGW to run the Code, on Windows 11.
First the getline Function couldn't be found, I resolved it by Copy-Pasting the getline Code of [this](https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/src/vms/getline.c) page, because the #include header's seemed not to work.

Comment: I don't recommend that you use the implementations of individual functions from other libraries. You should rather use the libraries that you have available. If the platform-specific function `getline` is truly unavailable, I recommend that you use the platform-neutral function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Why are you checking the return value of the first call to `getline`, but not checking the return value of  the second call to `getline`? Also, why are you calling `getline` a second time? Calling `getline` once per loop iteration would seem more appropriate.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel getline automatically allocates the memory. It makes memory management so much easier

Comment: @0___________ Almost as easy as C++ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You skip every second line as you read the line in the `while` then you read it again in the while body
2. You have a memory leak (same reason as point 1)

```
int main(void)                                          
{
    size_t l = 0;
    ssize_t retVal;
    char *line;

    line = NULL;
    do 
    {
        if((retVal = getline(&line,&l,stdin)) != -1)
        {
            printf("Buff_size:%zu Line_length: %zd Line:\"%s\"\n", l, retVal, line);

        }
    }while(retVal != -1);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code works even with the Copy-Pasted Version of the getline function.

Comment: agree about the double call to getline() but where is the memory leak?